# One message that cannot be deleted on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app, exchange-activesync

I have a single message in Mail on my iPhone 4 that just cannot be deleted. I get a popup saying **Unable to move message - The message could not be moved to the trash folder**.

I'm using the latest version of iOS. The account is an Exchange Active Sync account and deleting other messages is not a problem. I also use the same Exchange account from Outlook on my desktop and the message in question does not exist in Outlook. It only shows in Mail on iPhone.

I also have an another IMAP account on my iPhone and deleting isn't a problem on that account.

How can I remove this rogue message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that after a month the undeletable email would disappear from the mail app. This I can live with because I don't like the other option of setting up the Exchange account all over again.

Answer (score 3):

You could try removing the Exchange account completely and setting it up again. Maybe this also deletes the message.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like Mail got a bit out of sync and it can't move the message because it doesn't exist. Here are a few things you can do to get it to resync.

1. 'Quit' the Mail app - from the home screen, double 'click' the home button to show the list of recent apps. Press and hold the Mail app icon until it shakes and displays a red icon. Tap the red icon.
2. Restart your phone - always a good thing to try with software and caching problems.
3. Re-configure your mail account - this is a bit of a pain, but you should won't lose any messages because they are all on the server.

Comment: Thanks. I tried them, but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem occur recently with iPhone 5. After several days of trying everything under the sun I deleted the account and set it up from scratch. Not really a solution cause I'll be upset if I have to do this frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick way that worked.

- Go to the mail setting
- Unselect mail (checkbox) leave the others as they were.

This takes a minute or so and the corrupt e-mail go. Then reselect mail and the correct ones appear.

Answer (score -1):

Try this link.  there are several options to try.
http://appletoolbox.com/2014/03/ios-unable-to-move-message-fix/

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.